# Check for the value Of a var and reply If it includes the character "Hi"

Tags: javascript, html, char, include, indexof

My code:

```
<p id="test"></p>
<script>
var text="Hi I am Anonymous";
if text.IndexOf("Hi") {
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hey Anonymous";
return;
}//Sorry for the bad intending
</script>
```

I am trying to make a statement,if the var "test" includes the word/char "Hi".

Comment: I recommend working through some basic JavaScript tutorials. There are a number of really fundamental errors above. SO is good for targeted questions, not for general ground principals.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your advice, I have been introduced to javascript a month back,but I am experienced at Java, so thought of getting help in some javascript. Again Thanks :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is there a way you could help me solve this doubt I have?
I understand That This is not for general ground principles,could you give some advice/tutorial link,would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Open up the developer console. that will show you if your code has some errors. The code above should work if you put round brackets around the if condition: `if (text.indexOf("Hi")) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for `'Hi'` at index `0`.

```js
var text = "Hi I am Anonymous";

if (text.indexOf("Hi") === 0) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hey Anonymous";
}
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery its:

```
        var text="Hi I am Anonymous";

        if ($('#your_string').text().indexOf('Hi') > -1) {
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hey Anonymous";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas could you makea code snippet and send if you can as I am not able to figure it out ,again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read how indexOf() function works. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

```
if(text.indexOf("Hi")!=-1) {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Hey Anonymous";
  return;
}
```